# Why won't the font size increase inside my <td>

Tags: php, html, css, tcpdf

I have a PDF that is being generated by TCPDF in php.  The whole thing looks great, but I cant increase the size of font in any section of the table that is generated.  My CSS is not great, but any idea what I am doing wrong?

CSS:

```
   <style>
       }
       table.first {
           color: #003300;
           font-family: helvetica ;
           font-size: 8pt;
           border-left: 1px solid black;
           border-right: 1px solid black;
           border-top: 1px solid black;
           border-bottom: 1px solid black;
           background-color: white;
       }
       td {
           border: 1px solid black;
           background-color: white;
       }
   </style>
```

HTML:

```
    <table class="first" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
        <td width="50%"><B>1a.</b> Name of Insurance Plan (<B>OFFICE USE ONLY</b>):
                                        <BR>
                                        <BR><BR>
                                        <BR><B>1b.</b> Insurance I.D. Number (<B>UTAH ONLY</b> - Check with the patient and if they have Utah Medicaid and include the Medicaid I.D. Number.):
                                        <BR><BR><B><span style='font-size: 24pt;'>$medicaidid,</span></b>
                                        <BR><BR><B>1c.</b> Patient Name (Last Name, First Name) & DOB (Typed out, example: January 01, 1901):
                                        <BR><BR><B>$name</b>
                                        <BR><B>$dob</b><BR></td>
        <td width="50%"><B>2a.</b><BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="lilogo.png" style="width:8500%;" height="75">
                                <BR><B>2b.</b> Appointment Number: <BR><BR>        <B>$appid</b></td>

     </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: When I try your code, the span is up-sized. Maybe the issue is in another css block. Try using Development tool for Chrome or Firebug for Firefox

Comment: Have you tried setting the font-size directly for `td`s? User agents sometimes manipulate the table cell font size, and if TCPDF has a bug with CSS cascading, it might overwrite your `table` declaration down the road.

Comment: @Boldewyn changing the font size for the TD works, however I need only one line to be larger.  Any idea on how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the } under the style tag

This is your code:

```
<style>
       }
       table.first {
           color: #003300;
           font-family: helvetica;
```

Try this instead:

```
<style>
       table.first {
           color: #003300;
           font-family: helvetica;
```

Comment: Good catch! That might be the reason. (Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way!)

Comment: sori for the late response.. thanks Boldewyn for the welcome.. I always visit this site for resources and also to help other developers in just a simple way because that's all I can do.. ahehe I was surprised when I saw my reputation this day from 1 - 11.. thanks guys for the up rate.. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what are you trying to say, but on jsfiddle.net there is no issue regarding font size as for example when I tried,

```
*{
    font-size:20px;
}
```

it worked good or if you have any other issue, please be clear !